# Hadith about praying salah inbetween shade and sunlight

Tags: hadith, source-identification, reference-request

Today the Imam told us that the Prophet had prohibited praying while inbetween shade and sunlight.

**What is the full hadith and where does it come from?**

<sub>(Authenticity and Chain Of Narration)</sub>

Comment: Can you elaborate on the wordings of the Hadith?

Comment: Something along the lines of 'The Prophet prohibited praying while sitting half in shade and the other half in sunlight.'

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the below Hadiths:

> It was narrated from Ibn Buraidah, from his father, that the
> Prophet(ﷺ) : "forbade sitting between the shade and sun." 
> [Sunan Ibn
> Majah 3722](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3722)

and

> Narrated AbuHurayrah:
>
> AbulQasim (ﷺ) said: When one of you is in the sun (Shams)--Makhlad's
> version has "fay'"--and the shadow withdraws from him so that he is
> partly in sun and partly in shade, he should get up. [Sunan Abi Dawud
> 4821](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/43/49)

A [fatwa on IslamQA](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=26981) states :

It was reported that a Muslim is not allowed to sit with one half of his body in the shade and the other half in the sun. "The Prophet , forbade sitting between the shade and the sun." [Ibn Maajah, Al-Albaani: Saheeh]

Scholars said the reason for this prohibition is that the person is badly harmed due to the different opposite effects on him. However, it is more worthy to give the reason that was narrated i.e., **this is the way the devil sits, for the Prophet , forbade sitting partially in the sun and partially in the shade, and said: "This is how Satan sits."** [Ahmad, Al-Albaani: Saheeh]

This is similar to the prohibition of imitating Satan in eating and drinking with the left hand.

Comment: I hope al-Albani could fix the issue of the not cited narrator in the chain of the hadith from Sunan abi Dawud.